# Module of Kahler differentials of an affine variety

Tags: commutative-algebra

Here's a question I am working on but I'm unable to make sense of it because the notation is used very liberally. This question is based out of the chapter about Derivations in Matsumura, Commutative ring theory.

If $X$ is a variety over a field $k$ (let's assume $k$ is algebraically closed) and $P$ is a $k$-point on $X$ with maximal ideal $m_P$  then $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ modulo $m_P$ is a $k$-vector space naturally isomorphic to the dual of $m_P/m_P^2$. Now the rank of $\Omega^1_{X/k}$, as an $O_X$-module, equals the dimension of $X$, and so $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ is locally free in a neighbourhood of P if and only if X is smooth at P.

I believe $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ means $\Omega^1_{k[X]/k}$, where $k[X]$ is the coordinate ring. I believe the $\mathcal{O}_X$ also means the coordinate ring $k[X]$. The points of an affine variety are in one to one correspondence with maximal ideals in the variety's coordinate ring. So that's where maximal ideal associated with $P\in X$ comes from.

The terms I can't understand are "$\Omega^1_{X/k}$ modulo $m_P$", "dimension of X" and "locally free". I am not meant to use scheaves or schemes as in Hartsthorne to answer this.

Anyone got any ideas how to decode this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that you may interpret $\Omega^1_{X/k}$ as $\Omega^1_{k[X]/k}$ and $\mathcal{O}_X$ as $k[X]$ if you want to avoid speaking of sheaves. Now, to answer your questions:

**$\Omega^1_{X/k}$ modulo $m_P$:** Let $A$ be a commutative ring, let $\mathfrak{m}$ be an ideal of $A$, and let $M$ be an $A$-module. Then $\mathfrak{m}M := \{am\mid a\in\mathfrak{m}, m\in M\}$ is an $A$-submodule of $M,$ and we may form the quotient module $M/\mathfrak{m}M,$ which is naturally a module over $A/\mathfrak{m}.$ As a side note, $M/\mathfrak{m}M$ is isomorphic to $M\otimes_A A/\mathfrak{m}$.

**Dimension of $X$:** The dimension of a variety or scheme is its dimension as a topological space. This means that the dimension of $X$ is the supremum of the lengths of chains of irreducible closed subsets of $X$:
$$\dim X := \sup_{n}\{Z_0\subsetneq Z_1\subsetneq \cdots\subsetneq Z_n\subseteq X\mid Z_i\textrm{ closed irreducible subspace of }X\}.$$
In an affine scheme $X = \operatorname{Spec}A,$ such a chain corresponds to a chain  of prime ideals in $A,$ so that the dimension of $X$ is the same as the Krull dimension of $A.$

**Locally free:** This one is a little harder to make sense of without sheaves. You should know that to any morphism of schemes $f : X\to S,$ we may associate a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules $\Omega^1_{X/S}$ which is obtained by gluing together the sheaves of Kähler differentials on affine pieces. A sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$ is called *locally free* if for every point $x\in X,$ there exists an open neighborhood $U\ni x$ such that $\left.\mathcal{F}\right|_U\cong\mathcal{O}_U^n$ for some $n.$

Translating this back into a condition on your module, to be locally free in a neighborhood of $P$ means that there exists some $f\in A\setminus m_P$ such that the localization $M_f = M[f^{-1}]$ is isomorphic to a free $A_f = A[f^{-1}]$-module of some rank.

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Any ideas how I should go about establishing the isomorphism between the dual of the $m_p/m_p^2$ and $\Omega/m_p$? I have looked into the problem but it feels like there's a lemma or basic fact that either I don't know or I am forgetting. I know $m_p/m_p^2$, $\Omega\otimes k[X]/m_p$ and $\Omega_{(k[X]/m_p)/k}$ form an exact sequence, and there's the isomorphism that you pointed out too. But it's still not quite adding up

Comment: @coolpenguin If you have maps of algebras $R\to S\to S/I,$ and there exists a map of $R$-algebras $S/I\to S$ which is a section of $S\to S/I,$ the exact sequence $$I/I^2\to \Omega^1_{S/R}\otimes_S S/I\to\Omega^1_{(S/I)/R}\to 0$$ is in fact injective on the left, and so we have a short exact sequence $$0\to I/I^2\to \Omega^1_{S/R}\otimes_S S/I\to\Omega^1_{(S/I)/R}\to 0.$$ In your case, $R = k,$ $S = k[X],$ and $S/I = k[X]/m_P\cong k,$ so that we have $$0\to m_P/m_P^2\to\Omega^1_{k[X]/k}/m_P\to\Omega^1_{k/k}\to 0,$$ which gives you an isomorphism $m_P/m_P^2\cong\Omega^1/m_P.$

Comment: Isn't this only true when S is a local ring and I its maximal ideal? k[X] is not assumed to be a local ring here! Also, I want to prove the quotient module is isomorphic to the DUAL of the cotangent space. But thanks for your help!

Comment: @coolpenguin It is true more generally, see [lemma 10.131.10 in the stacks project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00RM). The claim about the dual space will follow by counting dimensions. I'm not sure how you are to get a natural identification of $\Omega^1/m_P$ with the dual space of $m_P/m_P^2,$ as there isn't a natural isomorphism between the identity functor for vector spaces and the functor which sends a vector space to its dual. Proposition 21.2.18 in [Vakil](https://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/216blog/FOAGnov1817public.pdf) is the statement you want, again without the dual.